# Macro to Remove Duplicates in Sheet based on Two Cells

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm trying to remove all duplicates in a sheet under the condition that the values in column A and B of one row are repeated in column A and B of any other row. The number of columns is irrelevant. Can someone show where I am going wrong?

My Current Code:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicate()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    lCount = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1
    Set rRange = sh.Range("A2:B" & lCount)

    For lCount = lCount To 1 Step -1
        With rRange("A" & lCount & ",B" & lCount)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rRange, .Value) > 1 Then
                .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next lCount

End Sub
```

Example:

```
|  A  |  B  |
|00001|12345| - KEEP
|00002|12345| - KEEP
|00003|12345| - KEEP
|00001|12346| - KEEP
|00001|12346| - REMOVE
|00001|12347| - KEEP
|00004|12345| - KEEP
|00002|12345| - REMOVE
```

Fixed Code:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicate()
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    lCount = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1
    sh.Range("A1:B" & lCount).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: error should be on this line `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rRange, .Value) > 1 Then`. When you call `.Value`, based on your `With` statement, excel returns an array, not a criteria. Try use the `CountIfs` function for your scenario

Comment: Try not to use `lCount` both for counting the number of rows and for iteration. You may declare a separate variable e.g. `i` for iteration purpose. that makes your code less confusing to yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use excels built in duplicate removal, for example

> ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2),
>   Header:=xlYes

Comment: Awesome, thanks ninjaRoche. I changed this to the accepted answer as it's much cleaner. Final Code edited above.

Answer (score 0):

What i mean is:

This block

```
With rRange("A" & lCount & ",B" & lCount)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rRange, .Value) > 1 Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End With
```

should be

```
If worksheetfunction.countifs( _
    sh.range("A2:A" & lcount), sh.range("A" & lcount), _
    sh.range("B2:B" & lcount), sh.range("B" & lcount)) > 0 Then 

    sh.range("A" & lcount).Entirerow.delete
end if
```

Comment: Seems like this is right.. but it's wiping out cells on a different tab. I'm not too familiar with macros - what's going on here?

Comment: just add `sh.` . I have edit my answer to show the change. Note that you have bind `sh` to the sheet named "Data"

Comment: Thanks for the help - I posted my final code above.

Comment: nice job. one more suggestion, instead of testing `If lCount > 1 Then`, you can remove it, and change `For lCount = lCount To 1 Step -1` to `For lCount = lCount To 2 Step -1`. That removes one burden of test, and probably speed up your code (slightly).